# Как добавить новые ветки из репозитория git

Tags: git, git-branch

Как залить к себе в локальный репозиторий ветви, вновь появившиеся в удаленном репозитории?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/Ветвление-в-Git-Удалённые-ветки - вам не нужно почти ничего, кроме справки на этом сайте. Все основные операции просто и доступно расписаны на русском.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Чтобы они просто появились в локальном репозитории:

```
git fetch
# если вдруг удалённых репозиториев несколько, можно указать имя
git fetch origin
```

При выполнении `git fetch` с удалённого репозитория в ваш локальный выкачиваются все имеющиеся в удалённом коммиты, которых у вас пока нет, а также все ветки. *Локально* создаются специальные ветки, которые повторяют содержание *удалённых* веток. Эти ветки имеют формат имени `<имя удалённого репозитория>/<имя ветки>`, например `origin/master`. Они отличаются тем, что в них вы не можете делать коммиты (тогда они перестанут быть копиями удалённых). Они предназначены для того, чтобы:

1. получать информацию о структуре веток на удалённом репозитории
2. делать из них соответствующие локальные ветки
3. иным образом забирать из них коммиты в локальные ветки

Узнать, из чего можно выбрать (варианты равнозначны):

```
git branch -a
git branch --all
```

Переключиться на ветку просто чтобы посмотреть

```
git checkout <origin/имя ветки>
```

Посмотреть, чем отличаются между собой две ветки (cпасибо [KoVadim](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/2739/kovadim) за идею):

```
git diff <origin/первая ветка> .. <origin/вторая ветка>
```

Создать свою локальную ветку из удалённой, чтобы потом делать коммиты в локальную и сразу настроить, чтобы пушить в эту удалённую. Это нужно **только если вы хотите продолжать разработку в этой ветке**.

```
git checkout -b <имя ветки> <origin/имя ветки>
```

Подробнее в [Pro Git - 3.5 Ветвление в Git - Удалённые ветки](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-Git-%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8).

Comment: я использовал `git fetch` но ветки из удаленного репо не появились в локальном репо - как так?

Comment: они появились, просто не совсем так, как Вы это ожидаете. Можно конечно сделать маленький однострочник на баше, но смысла в этом большого не вижу.

Comment: git branch показывает **локальные ветки**, делайте `git branch -a`, что бы увидеть все ветки и связи

Comment: да, могут быть. Если хотите посмотреть изменения, это всегда можно сделать после fetch/pull используя diff - `git diff <origin/первая ветка> .. <origin/вторая ветка>`

Comment: при git pull/fetch все изменения выкачиваются. Даже если их очень-очень много. И для этого не нужно делать checkout каждой ветки отдельно. Это не svn.

Comment: ребят, я все равно не втыкаю...    сделал я у себя `git fetch`, но после команды `git branch` не вижу залитых к себе веток с удаленного репо...  как мне после фетча получить доступ к якобы залитым веткам? а вот совет про __переключиться, чтобы посмотреть__ это классная подсказка

Comment: @buyboy вы выполняете команду `git branch` или `git branch -all`?. Сколько у вас удаленных репозиториев, что возвращает команда `git remote -v`?

Comment: @NickVolynkin  команда `git branch -a` возвращает две локальные ветки и три удаленные типа remotes/origin/blah-blah-blah, а команда `git remote -v` возвращает два удаленных сервера с с одинаковыми путями и алиасами, но в конце у них стоит <fetch> и <push>

Comment: @NickVolynkin  ща проплюсую и поставлю галочку!

Answer (score 1):

Допустим у Вас есть удалённая ветка *origin/somebranch*
Можно воспользоваться сокращённой командой. Это создаст новую локальную ветку, привяжет её к удалённой ветке и переключится на нее:
`git checkout somebranch`
`git pull`

Второй вариант, где можно задать своё локальное имя ветки.
Это создаст новую локальную ветку и привяжет ветку слежения за удалённой веткой к ней и переключится на неё:
`git checkout -b name-local-branch origin/somebranch`
`git pull`